# Mockmvc unit testing with String[] as request body

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc

I'm trying to create a unit test for the PUT api, as seen below, with a String[] as the request body.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/id", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateStatus(@RequestBody String[] IdList,.........){
}
```

and my test is shown below

```
@Test
public void updateStatus() throws Exception {
    when(serviceFactory.getService()).thenReturn(service);        
    mockMvc.perform(put(baseUrl + "/test/id)
        .param("IdList",new String[]{"1"}))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

The test is failing with this exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
```

What could be the best way to pass a string array param from mockmvc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting your String[] in param. You sohuld put it in body. You can put it like that(I am assuming you are using json. If you use xml you can change it accordingly):

```
ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper();
String requestJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(new String[]{"1"});
mockMvc.perform(put(baseUrl + "/test/id)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(requestJson)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0]", is("1")));
```

`jsonPath` is `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath`

Comment: hi @barbakini what if my request body changes, it is not throwing any error when I changed the body

Comment: @BrijanElwadhi why do you expect to throw any error? That code above is just putting `requestJson` into body. If you mean to fail the test based on body's value, you can use and other `.andExpect()` method to check body's value. I will edit

Comment: @barbakini thank you so much for quick reply,  As I am new to Juint can you please give some reference  where i can see how check request body in andExpect() method

Comment: @BrijanElwadhi In test method, you are putting request body already, so no need to check in my opinion. With andExpect you can check response body(My previous comment was in a rush and mislead) But If you are trying to test your controller method if it throws an expected exception based on request body's value. Just put necessary value in request body and annotate your test method like `@Test(expected = YourException.class)`